# Unusual Occurrence in Django's Main Thread

Tags: python, django

I am encountering errors when attempting to execute my Django project using the command

```py
python manage.py runserver
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just quickly looking at the stack trace it is clearly a problem with the database. Have you run makemigrations and/or migrate? If so, are your migrations valid across the project and do you have an `__init__.py` file under the migrations directory?

Comment: Yes, i have  a __init__.py and i try migrate before, its doesnt work

Comment: Check the solution in **[this](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/psycopg2-errors-undefinedtable-relation-api-customuser-does-not-exist/14498)** page.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors or other text. Copy the original text to your question instead